# Obtaining an expression between $s'(n,r)$ and $s(n,r)$

Tags: problem-solving

I've a doubt in this:

> We're given $[x]_n=(x)(x-1)\ldots (x-(n-1))$ and $[x]^n=(x)(x+1)\ldots (x+n-1)$ .
>   Now as we can write :
>          $[x]_n=(x)(x-1)\ldots (x-(n-1))=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2\ldots +a_nx^n$.
>
> Here the coefficient of $x^r$ in expansion i.e. $a_r$is denoted as $s(n,r)$.
>
> Hence we write:
>          $$[x]_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}s(n,r)x^r$$
>   Similarly my notes state
>              $$[x]^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}s'(n,r)x^r$$
>
> then the following relation is directly written in my notes: 
>               $$s'(n,r)=(-1)^{n-r}s(n,r)$$

How can we obtain this last relation is what I can't understand....Please help how to obtain this expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. You have $$ \begin{align}[x]_n&=(x)(x-1)\ldots (x-(n-1))\\
&=(-1)^{n}(-x)((-x)+1)\ldots ((-x)+n-1)\\
&=(-1)^{n}[-x]^n
\end{align}$$ then you identify your polynomials.

Hope you can take it from here.